# Link several values together in Postgres

Tags: python, sql, database, mongodb, postgresql

From MongoDB I have two collections: collection "A" has columns "a", "b", "c" and collection "B": "c", "d", "e".
My goal is to create Postgres table "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" and continuously update data in Postgres from MongoDB. The problem is if "d" or "e" has been changed -> I have to update all corresponding "c" in joined table in Postgres, which is very slow.
Is there a way to somehow link "c" values between them so they can be updated simultaneously in whole table.

Comment: What you mean "you have to update corresponding c in joined table"? How your database is defined in Postgres? Do you really have five tables or two tables with three columns in each? If so what columns you have in each of those tables.

Comment: @ex4 Let`s say, 1st collection is purchases with user_id column. 2nd collection - user info, including user_id.My goal is to store these two joined collections in Postgres as one table. I can have a lot of purchases made by one user, therefore, if user info updates I will have to update this info for every purchase user have ever made.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike MongoDB, Postgres is a relational database. It seems that you are trying to use it like no-SQL database. There is an excellent Wikipedia article about database normalization. Take a look at that concept. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

In your example, you probably want to have two tables. One for users and one for purchases. There is one field in your purchases table which is foreign key referring to your user table. When there is new sales or you modify old ones, you don't need to modify your user table.

When doing queries against that database, you use JOIN and you get your result just as all data was in one table.